# Rename Devices in Pipewire

Tags: arch-linux, audio, wayland

I am using ArchLinux with i3. I recently switched from PulseAudio to Pipewire,
since I want to switch also to Wayland and Sway in the near future.

For now, Pipewire works perfectly. Nevertheless, I have a little problem.

I am using audio devices with the same Description, so I cannot distinguish them in Pavucontrol for example.
Using Pulse, I wrote an update-sink-proplist statement into my local default.pa file.

Does someone know, how to do this with Pipewire, i.e. how can I change the description
of a device, if this device is connected.

Currently, I am using the default configuration of Pipewire.

My approaches:

- I guess this probably works with pw-metadata, but I did not find the right command.
- I added the following in ~/.config/pipewire/media-session.d/alsa-monitor.conf

```
{
    matches = [
        {
            node.name = "~^alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.output_analog-stereo$"
        }

    ]
    actions = {
        update-props = {
             device.description = "Laptop"
        }
    }
}
```

This changed the corresponding entry in the list of properties in the output of `pactl list sinks`, but  not the actual description. Indeed, the output is

```
Sink #45
    ...
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.output_analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo Output
    ...
    Properties:
        ...
        device.description = "Laptop"
        ...
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your own answer (`node.description` is the property to be updated), the configuration you stated needs to be embedded in a `rules = [...]` block in `~/.config/pipewire/media-session.d/alsa-monitor.conf`:

```
rules = [
  {
    matches = [
      {
        node.name = "~^alsa_output.pci-0000_0d_00.4.analog-stereo$"
      }
    ]
    actions = {
      update-props = {
        node.description = "Headphones"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Further hints in [PipeWire's Wiki](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Config-pipewire-media-session#matching-rules).

Comment: Newbie here: how do I make that description actually appear in Settings > Sound > Output > Output Device?

Comment: Same question. I added the file (I had to create directories `pipewire/media-session.d` and the `alsa-monitor.conf` file in `~/.config`, since they were not there. I don't see any changes.

Answer (score 5):

If you're following the current recommendation, using [WirePlumber](https://pipewire.pages.freedesktop.org/wireplumber/index.html) instead of [PipeWire Media Session](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/media-session), the way to change a node's description (or any other property) is to create a Lua script and add it into `~/.config/wireplumber` under the proper path and name.

For instance, to change the description of an ALSA node as felix wants, you would create a file such as `~/.config/wireplumber/main.lua.d/51-alsa-rename.lua` with the following content:

```lua
rule = {
  matches = {
    {
      { "node.name", "equals", "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.output_analog-stereo" },
    },
  },
  apply_properties = {
    ["node.description"] = "Laptop",
  },
}

table.insert(alsa_monitor.rules,rule)
```

If instead you wish to change something on a Bluetooth node or device, you could create `~/.config/wireplumber/bluetooth.lua.d/51-rename.lua` with a content such as:

```lua
rule = {
  matches = {
    {
      { "node.name", "equals", "bluez_output.02_11_45_A0_B3_27.a2dp-sink" },
    },
  },
  apply_properties = {
    ["node.nick"] = "Headphones",
  },
}

table.insert(bluez_monitor.rules,rule)
```

The Lua scripts' filenames and locations are thus devised in a way that allows [WirePlumber's Multi-path merging](https://pipewire.pages.freedesktop.org/wireplumber/configuration/config_lua.html#multi-path-merging) to run them just after the default config files (e.g. `/usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua`) but before the file that loads and enables the devices (e.g. `/usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/90-enable-all.lua`).

The properties that you can change as well as the matching rules to select devices or nodes are documented at [ALSA configuration](https://pipewire.pages.freedesktop.org/wireplumber/configuration/alsa.html) and [Bluetooth configuration](https://pipewire.pages.freedesktop.org/wireplumber/configuration/bluetooth.html).

Answer (score 2):

[dllud's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688554/329319) regarding WirePlumber is on the right track, but in case anyone comes across this after 2023, Lua is out and [SPA-JSON](https://pipewire.pages.freedesktop.org/wireplumber/daemon/configuration/conf_file.html#the-spa-json-format) is the new hotness.

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.config/wireplumber/wireplumber.conf.d
touch ~/.config/wireplumber/wireplumber.conf.d/99-renames.conf
```

The exact filename is not important.

The format looks like this:

```
monitor.alsa.rules = [
    {
        matches = [
            { node.name = "alsa_output.usb-Turtle_Beach_Elo_7.1_Air_8502FFFF8102-01.analog-stereo" }
        ],
        actions = {
            update-props = {
                node.description   = "Headset",
                device.form-factor = "headset",
                device.icon-name   = "audio-headset-symbolic",
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Restart wireplumber with

```bash
systemctl --user restart wireplumber.service
```

You can grab properties to match and change with `wpctl status` and `wpctl inspect ##`, where `##` is the ID number listed by `wpctl status`.

On my system (openSUSE Tumbleweed), examples are found in `/usr/share/doc/wireplumber/examples/wireplumber.conf.d`.  The `alsa.conf` file in particular is what I used for the above.

More documentation can be found here: https://pipewire.pages.freedesktop.org/wireplumber/daemon/configuration/alsa.html

Fingers crossed that it stays stable for more than two years.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got the answer.

In my second try, it has to be `node.description` instead of `device.description`.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered. You can even answer your own questions.